# drive visibility on ubuntu that has formatted by windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs, multi-boot

i always use windows and now i want to install ubuntu as my second OS(multi boot)
i'll install ubuntu on separate drive.

will i be able to see my other drives that were formatted by windows?
the drives formatted as NTFS and GPT(and then NTFS) maybe also FAT32. if there is some drives that i will be able to see and some that will not please say which..

by the way the ubuntu drive - i will be able to see through win?

thanks.

Comment: ubuntu will be able to see and read (unless encrypted) the windows formatted drives. depending on what you use for the ubuntu partitions (eg ext4) windows won't understand what it is and will show it as unknown/unrecognised and tell you to format it before can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to view the contents of the windows drives through ubuntu but not the other way around.

To windows, the ubuntu drive will show up as unformatted or not readable and windows will prompt you to format it.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said you will not be able to read the Ubuntu drive in Windows, but you cna create a shared drive between the two that would allow for cross data usage. Generally this third drive will be partitioned in NTFS although there are some other choices. Your best bet is to format and set up the drive in Windows to avoid permissions errors.